# How to programmatically send MMS in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, mms

How to programmatically send an MMS in blackberry?

Comment: Which version of the OS?  4.5?

Comment: Are you looking for a MMS SDK for Blackberry? Or is this a program that your developing on the phone to send MMS?

Comment: It's a program that I'm working on which will send MMS

Comment: For OS 4.6 and higher MMS is in the API - are you after an example of this?

Comment: @ martin - yes, I'm after working example for this but I'm using 4.5 OS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### MMS API (4.6 and >)

There is a [net.rim.blackberry.api.mms](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mms/MMS.html)  class which "Provides advanced utilities for interaction with the MMS messaging system.". But this gives only ability to "modify the message before it is sent or deny it from being sent completely" using [addSendListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mms/MMS.html#addSendListener(net.rim.blackberry.api.mms.SendListener))

### Using MMS protocol in connection

from [javax.microedition.io.Connector API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/io/Connector.html#mms):

**mms**
This protocol opens an MMS connection across the wireless network. The open request should be formatted as follows:

```
(MessageConnection) Connector.open("mms://[<peer_address >]:[<application_Id>]");
```

where:

- < peer_address > is the phone number or the email address of recipient.
- < application_Id > is used to identify a Java application.

For example, to send a mms message to specific application use

```
Connector.open("mms://+123456789:applicationID");
```

To open a server mode MessageConnection use

```
Connector.open("mms://:applicationID");
```

Also see [Introduction of MMS in J2ME](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/articles/MMS_20060901.pdf) and sample code - [How to send MMS?](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-send-MMS/td-p/147549) and [Sending and Receiving MMS on J2ME devices](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/sending-and-recieving-mms-on-j2me-devices.html)

I have never tried this approach, so I can't tell if it's working.

### Invoking Messages application

Other option is open Messages application programmatically, to compose MMS:

```
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES,
 new MessageArguments(MessageArguments.ARG_NEW_MMS));
```

Also see [Invoking MMS with attachment using application.](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Invokeing-MMS-with-attachment-using-application/td-p/189929)

Comment: Good - but the OP commented that the OS is v4.5 :(

Comment: According to this link

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-send-MMS/td-p/147549

the native J2ME method to send MMS doesn't work with blackberry

Comment: @Ali El-sayed Ali - there must be some reason why mms protocol is included in javadocs. maybe its require some configured server or something.